# Текст вылазит за рамки

Tags: html, css

Есть див блок, фон установлен изображением, все работает но текст вылезает за блок и создаётся прокрутка. В чём проблема?

```
 .container {
 background-image: url('images/img.jpg');
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 }

  <div clasd="container">Какой нибудь длинный текст</div>
```

Comment: clasd="container" - здесь опечатка

Comment: можешь пожалуйста добавить рабочий пример кода, где воспроизводится данная проблема, с приведенными тобой стилями данная проблема невозможна

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте добавить `word-wrap: break-word`